# Htacces to nginx (crowdphp)

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

Can someone explain me how can i rewrite this to make it work with php-fpm (vestacp)?

It's a CrowdPHP script. Atm we need to move to php-fpm server, but... seems it is impossible to make a proper nginx template for this. I've tried to use some online converters, but nothing works.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^project\/(.*)-id-([0-9]+)\.html$  index.php?ctl=deal&act=show&id=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^project\/updates\/(.\d)\/$  index.php?ctl=deal&act=update&id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^project\/comments\/(.\d)\/$  index.php?ctl=deal&act=comment&id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^user\/(.\d)\/$  index.php?ctl=home&id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^user\/(.\d)\/funded\/$  index.php?ctl=home&act=support&id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#Custom Rerites 
#RewriteRule ^projects-we-like.html$  index.php?ctl=article&id=77



RewriteRule ^article_cate$  index.php\?ctl=article_cate [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(about|Help|events|media|about-us|how-to)$  index.php\?ctl=article_cate&bs=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(about|Help|events|media|about-us|how-to)/([^\.&]*)\.html$  index.php\?ctl=article&id=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^\.&]*)\.html$  index.php\?rewrite_param=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
# nginx configuration location /project { rewrite ^/project\/(.*)-id-([0-9]+)\.html$ /index.php?ctl=deal&act=show&id=$2 break; rewrite ^/project\/updates\/(.\d)\/$ /index.php?ctl=deal&act=update&id=$1 break; rewrite ^/project\/comments\/(.\d)\/$ /index.php?ctl=deal&act=comment&id=$1 break; } location /user { rewrite ^/user\/(.\d)\/$ /index.php?ctl=home&id=$1 break; rewrite ^/user\/(.\d)\/funded\/$ /index.php?ctl=home&act=support&id=$1 break; } location / { if (!-e $request_filename){ rewrite ^/article_cate$ /index.php\?ctl=article_cate break; } rewrite ^/([^\.&]*)\.html$ /index.php\?rewrite_param=$1 break; } location /about { rewrite ^/(about|Help|events|media|about-us|how-to)$ /index.php\?ctl=article_cate&bs=$1 break; rewrite ^/(about|Help|events|media|about-us|how-to)/([^\.&]*)\.html$ /index.php\?ctl=article&id=$2 break; } location /Help { rewrite ^/(about|Help|events|media|about-us|how-to)$ /index.php\?ctl=article_cate&bs=$1 break; rewrite ^/(about|Help|events|media|about-us|how-to)/([^\.&]*)\.html$ /index.php\?ctl=article&id=$2 break; } location /events { rewrite ^/(about|Help|events|media|about-us|how-to)$ /index.php\?ctl=article_cate&bs=$1 break; rewrite ^/(about|Help|events|media|about-us|how-to)/([^\.&]*)\.html$ /index.php\?ctl=article&id=$2 break; } location /media { rewrite ^/(about|Help|events|media|about-us|how-to)$ /index.php\?ctl=article_cate&bs=$1 break; rewrite ^/(about|Help|events|media|about-us|how-to)/([^\.&]*)\.html$ /index.php\?ctl=article&id=$2 break; } location /about-us { rewrite ^/(about|Help|events|media|about-us|how-to)$ /index.php\?ctl=article_cate&bs=$1 break; rewrite ^/(about|Help|events|media|about-us|how-to)/([^\.&]*)\.html$ /index.php\?ctl=article&id=$2 break; } location /how-to { rewrite ^/(about|Help|events|media|about-us|how-to)$ /index.php\?ctl=article_cate&bs=$1 break; rewrite ^/(about|Help|events|media|about-us|how-to)/([^\.&]*)\.html$ /index.php\?ctl=article&id=$2 break; }
```

Comment: that's the one, that i've already tried. It was auto generated via some online converter. Nginx does not load with that template.

Comment: @Daniel, yes its autogenerate from https://winginx.com/en/htaccess
It may help you to generate from htaccess to nginx configuration.

Comment: you need to customize as per your server setting and required url.